# Is there any way to 'reserve' some memory for a struct to make sure other functions can't overwrite it?

Tags: c, dictionary, pointers, memory, singly-linked-list

For context, I'm a new programmer to C and I wanted to make a toy implementation of a dictionary/map from a 'Person' struct to an integer. I'm using separate chaining, so I have a hash table of linked list pointers.

So far, I've been able to add one value to the linked list just fine, but when I call the function to get the value for the Person key I'm using, the memory at one of my nodes seems to get overwritten.

More info if it's helpful, using a singly linked list with one sentinel node at the head and a tail reference.

New to StackOverflow, so I can't actually embed the image, but pictured on left is the HashTable at the beginning of the function call, when nothing has been changed. The relevant stuff is the expanded part of the Variables menu, which shows that at position 58 is a pointer to 0x61f8e0, the linked list. The linked list has a head pointer to 0x61f760, which is the sentinel value, and a tail pointer to 0x61f864, currently pointing to a Node with the value (3) for a Person named Robert who's 36 years old. The tail pointer's next field points to 0x0 (not pictured), like intended. The picture follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9EJ9.png

This is what happens as soon as the first statement (which hashes the Person pointer very naively) is executed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJvGy.png. As you'll see, the value is now some random long number, the intrinsic age is now 1 instead of 36, the saved name is now gibberish, and worst of all the next pointer now points somewhere completely random (0x61fb10).

The function in question follows.

```
int tableGet(HashTable t, Person key) {
    int position = hash(&key) % 100;
    List* listLoc = t.table[position];
    if ((int) listLoc == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    Node curr = *(listLoc -> head);
    while (curr.next != NULL) {
        if (curr.savedAge == key.age && curr.savedName == key.name) {
            return curr.val;
        }
        curr = *curr.next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Here is the hash function, in case that's what's causing the problems.

```
int hash(Person* p) {
    int sum;
    Person person = *p;
    int i = 0;
    char nameChar = person.name[i];
    while (nameChar != '\0'){
        sum += (int) nameChar;
        i += 1;
        nameChar = person.name[i];
    }
    return (int) (person.age + sum);
}
```

And just because why not, here's all of the short amount of code I've written for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>  

typedef struct Node {
    int val;
    int savedAge;
    char savedName[100];
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    int age;
    char name[100];
} Person;

typedef struct {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
} List;

typedef struct {
    List* table[100];
} HashTable;

int hash(Person*);

Person person(int age, char name[]) {
    Person p;
    p.age = age;
    strcpy(p.name, name);
    return p;
}

Node node(int val, Person p, Node* next) {
    Node n;
    n.val = val;
    strcpy(n.savedName, p.name);
    n.savedAge = p.age;
    n.next = next;
    return n;
}

List list() {
    List l;
    Node head = node(-1, person(0, "SENTINEL"), NULL);
    l.head = &head;
    l.tail = l.head;
    return l;
}

void listAdd(List* l, Node n) {
    Node* newTailPtr = &n;
    l -> tail -> next = newTailPtr;
    l -> tail = newTailPtr;
}

HashTable table() {
    int table[100] = {0};
    HashTable t;
    memcpy(t.table, table, sizeof table);
    return t;
}

HashTable tableAdd(HashTable t, Person key, int val) {
    int num = hash(&key) % 100;
    List* loc = t.table[num];
    if ((int) loc == 0) {
        List newList = list();
        t.table[num] = &newList;
    }
    listAdd((List*) t.table[num], node(val, key, NULL));
    return t;
}

int tableGet(HashTable t, Person key) {
    int position = hash(&key) % 100;
    List* listLoc = t.table[position];
    if ((int) listLoc == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    Node curr = *(listLoc -> head);
    while (curr.next != NULL) {
        if (curr.savedAge == key.age && curr.savedName == key.name) {
            return curr.val;
        }
        curr = *curr.next;
    }
    return -1;
}

int hash(Person* p) {
    int sum;
    Person person = *p;
    int i = 0;
    char nameChar = person.name[i];
    while (nameChar != '\0'){
        sum += (int) nameChar;
        i += 1;
        nameChar = person.name[i];
    }
    return (int) (person.age + sum);
}

int main() {
    Person bob = person(36, "Robert");
    printf(bob.name);
    printf("\n");
    HashTable tab = table();
    tab = tableAdd(tab, bob, 3);
    printf("Added Robert to table as 3\n");
    int val = tableGet(tab, bob);
    if (val == 3) {
        printf("Success!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failure, val is %d\n", val);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `listAdd` is broken. It stores the address of the function parameter that goes out of scope at the end of the function leaving you with a dangling pointer to invalid memory. The `list` function is also broken for the same reason, storing a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Not the problem you're looking for now, but the `sum` variable in the `hash` function needs to be initialized, e.g. `int sum = 0;`

Comment: The real problem is that you need to learn to better understand and use pointers. You are passing structs as values to functions, which is often a bad idea. And you are dereferencing pointers you shouldn't. There's plenty of implementations of linked lists around to use as reference. Study them.

Comment: Rather than making some project, go back to the beginning and become used to forming and manipulating a simple linked list... What you've shown here entangles an incorrect implementation of a linked list with clutter about "people and ages"... You've got to master crawling before you can walk; before you can run...

Comment: If other code in your program is improperly overwriting your data, the correct solution is to *identify and fix that other code*.  There isn't any way to "protect" data from its own program, and even if there were, it would not fix the actual underlying bug that the other code is not doing what it should.  Now, if you can't *find* which code is overwriting it, there are debugging tools that will halt the program for debugging when the data in question is written to.  See if your favorite debugger supports "watchpoints" or "data breakpoints".

Comment: Thanks all, especially Retired Ninja - that helped me find the problem. I was wrongly assuming the local variable pointer worked the same way as references. @Fe2O3 A couple of commenters have said similar things (there was one comment yesterday which is no longer here), but could I ask you to expand on what you mean? I know the tail reference isn't normal for singly-linked lists. Coming from a CS B class our instructor had showed us an implementation which used the same dummy node strategy. Is the problem with my implementation in how I'm using C features or does my strategy just suck?

Comment: "suck"? Wrong word... "too complex", maybe... Here's a function simplified: `int hash(Person *p) { int sum=p->age; for(int i=0; p->name[i]; i++) sum+=p->name[i]; return sum; }` Strive to write `C`lear, `C`lean, `C`oncise `C`ode... The name of the language is `C`... (In your version, sum started uninitialised... Bad, but hard to see in all the verbiage.)